# FMX - Cancel URL loading

Tags: delphi-xe5, twebbrowser, firemonkey-fm3

Is there any way to cancel URL loading using property [`TCustomWebBrowser.OnShouldStartLoadWithRequest`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.WebBrowser.TCustomWebBrowser.OnShouldStartLoadWithRequest)?
Type of this property is declared as

```
TWebBrowserShouldStartLoadWithRequest = procedure(ASender: TObject; const URL: string) of object;
```

So it doesn't return any value based on which one could decide whether to stop or continue URL loading...

Comment: If you want more attention on your question you should add the `delphi` tag

Comment: @SirRufo, no, thank you. I'm almost sure that the answer is 'No'; I don't want to bother people:)